# Intellij does not detect type of list

Tags: java, linux, list, intellij-idea

I never had that issue.
I can't use any type of loop over an arraylist.

That is the error: Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Lmt.png

My code of the first class:

```
    private List<String> aliases = new ArrayList<>();

    ....

    
    public final List<String> getAliasesList() {
        return aliases;
    }
```

The code with the error in the other class:

```
        this.subCommands.put(subCommand.getName().toLowerCase(), subCommand);
        if (subCommand.hasAliases()) {
            for (String alias : subCommand.getAliasesList()) {//here is the error

            }
        }
```

What I did?

1. Check version of system packages (and update) -> Elementary OS 5.1
2. Check IntelliJ-Idea-Ultimate Version -> 2021.1.2

Some information:
language level: 8
Java-Version: openJDK11
OS-Version: elementaryOS 5.1 (Hera)
CPU (GPU): AMD Ryzen 3 2200G (Vega 8)
RAM: 24 GB Hyper X DDR4

Thank you for reading and maybe for helping

Comment: Post text rather than images wherever practical.

Comment: Your error refers to a parameter named `alias`, but you did not show us any such thing in your Question. Voting to close as lacking debugging details.